# Java Android Property file

Tags: java, android, properties, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to load some data saved in my property file in an Android Application.

I have put my property file under the src folder. Every time I try to load data from my file it keeps telling me FileNotFoundException open failed ENOENT (No such file or directory).

My Code is as follows:

This code is to save the file (new create)

```
      File file = new File("src/com/example/testphonegap/SilverAngel.properties");
      FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
      properties.store(fileOut, "Properties");
      fileOut.close();
```

This code is to load data

```
    properties = new Properties();
    InputStream is = null;

     // First try loading from the current directory
    try {
        File f = new File("src/com/example/testphonegap/SilverAngel.properties");
        is = new FileInputStream(f);

        // Try loading properties from the file (if found)
        properties.load(is);

        GetPersonaliseSettings();
        GetUserSettings();
        GetFavSettings();
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) { 
        is = null; 
    }
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong please? Is it where the file is saved or am I missing something in my code?

Comment: have you tried changing the directory to a location outside like in a newfolder in the external memory

Comment: No.. How can I do that please

Comment: File f = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/YourFolderName");

Comment: Put that file in the projectDirectory/res/raw, instead of src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an Android Application, so the file is stored on the Android device and not on your computer.
If you want to save the file on the SD card you can write the following:

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File dir = new File(root + "/subfolderForYourApp");
dir.mkdirs();
```

This will create a subfolder for your application on the SD card.
To create a new file in this directory:

```
File file = new File(dir, "SilverAngel.properties");
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
properties.store(fileOut, "Properties");
fileOut.close();
```

Don't forget to add the permission to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/example/testphonegap/SilverAngel.properties");
properties.load(inputStream);
```

make sure you don't add "src" before property file name.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the assets folder and load it from there.

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("SilverAngel.properties");
properties.load(inputStream);
```